# Mysql Windows Forms | Connection must be valid and open

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

Good day, friends, help to finalize this class, here's the thing:
I'm trying to make it so that if there is no connection to the database, one action will be performed in the form, there will be a connection to the database, we perform another action.

Now the problem is that if you do not connect to the database, there will be terrible lags of the application itself.

```
    using System;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Launcher.SupportClass
{
    public class Web_MysqlDataBase : IDisposable
    {
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=root;password=1234;database=test-test;");

        public bool Connection_BD;
        public void OpenConnect()
        {
            if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    CheckConnect();
                }
                catch 
                {
                    CheckConnect();
                }
                finally
                {
                    CheckConnect();
                    closedConnection();
                }

            }
        }
        public void closedConnection()
        {
            if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
        public MySqlConnection getConnection()
        {
            return connection;
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
        }
        public void CheckConnect()
        {
            if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                Connection_BD = true;
            }
            if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                Connection_BD = false;
            }
        }
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // free managed resources
                if (connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    connection.Close();
                    connection = null;
                    Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Next, I want to perform this simple construction, but there are already errors, what am I doing wrong?

```
                        Web_MysqlDataBase bd = new Web_MysqlDataBase();
        bd.OpenConnect();
        string query = "SELECT `text_update` FROM `launcher` WHERE `opened`='1'";
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, bd.getConnection());
        if (bd.Connection_BD == true)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            adapter.Fill(table);
            if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                string name = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                ScrollingLeable.Text = name;
                ScrollingLeable.position = 750;
                ScrollsLeable.Visible = true;
                ScrollingLeable.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ScrollsLeable.Visible = false;
                ScrollingLeable.Visible = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ScrollsLeable.Visible = false;
            ScrollingLeable.Visible = false;
        }
```

Comment: that because it waits everytome till it hits the timeout or check before hand ia connection is open and skip

Comment: What then? How do I make this simple design better?

Comment: you have to debug it , and find the spots where it lags there can not be many paces where you use a database connection that isn't open

Comment: Read [ask].  "but there are already errors", do you expect us to guess what they are?  Please [Edit] your post to include whatever error messages you are getting.

Comment: `code` string name = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString(); My Problem Here   
System.InvalidOperationException: "Connection must be valid and open."

Comment: @Jwdonahue Are you sure you looked at the code, or just decided to write it?

Comment: your finally statement in your open method is closing the connection...and not setting your property back that it's actually closed

Comment: @ Ctznkane525 How do I do it then?